# Container decoration disappears after TextFormField click

Tags: flutter, dart

When I click on container with child TextFormField, decoration disappears.

This is the current behavior of the app:

[image: App TextFormField]

Seems like a problem with `backgroundBlendMode` property, but I can't figure out, how to create same design without it.

```dart
  static Decoration _buttonDecoration = BoxDecoration(
      backgroundBlendMode: BlendMode.modulate,
      color: Color(0xFF938890),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(45)));

  Widget _emailTextField = _createTextField('Email', TextInputType.emailAddress,
      Icon(Icons.email, color: Colors.white));

  Widget _passwordTextField = _createTextField(
      'Password',
      TextInputType.text,
      Icon(
        Icons.lock,
        color: Colors.white,
      ));

static Widget _createTextField(
      String hintText, TextInputType textInputType, Icon icon) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
      decoration: _buttonDecoration,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
      width: 250,
      child: TextFormField(
        focusNode: FocusNode(),
        obscureText: textInputType == TextInputType.text ? true : false,
        maxLines: 1,
        keyboardType: textInputType,
        autocorrect: true,
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: InputBorder.none,
            icon: icon,
            hintText: hintText,
            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Did you try to remove static keyword?

Comment: @mathronaut yes, still have the same behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things you need to change on your code.

- First of all, don't use a `Container` to decorate the `TextFormField` as this widget already handles that kind of styling.
- Use `prefixIcon` instead of `icon` to keep it inside the `TextFormField` if that's what you want.
- If you need to set the size of a widget (without width property) is a better option to use `SizedBox`.
- It's not directly related, but don't use methods returning widgets. You should create separate `Stateless` or `Stateful` widgets.

Here you have an example:

```
OutlineInputBorder _outlineBorder = OutlineInputBorder(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(45)),
  borderSide: BorderSide(
    style: BorderStyle.none,
  ),
);


SizedBox(
  width: 250.0,
  child: TextFormField(
    style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      border: _outlineBorder,
      enabledBorder: _outlineBorder,
      focusedBorder: _outlineBorder,
      prefixIcon: Icon(
        Icons.mail,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      hintText: 'Email',
      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      filled: true,
      fillColor: Colors.black45.withOpacity(0.4),
    ),
  ),
),
```

UPDATE:

Tested it and forgot to apply the same style to `enabledBorder` and `focusedBorder`. That way the border color doesn't change when focusing on the `TextFormField`. I've updated the code to reflect that.